# Joining 3 tables Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 3 tables listing below:

Table_A:

```
order_number | header_id
        123  | 80001
```

Table_B

```
   header_id | line_id | quantity
       80001 | 10001   | 1
       80001 | 10002   | 3
       80001 | 10003   | 5
```

Table_C

```
   header_id | line_id | hold_price_id | released_flag
       80001 |   10001 | 2001          | Y
       80001 |   10002 | 2002          | Y
       80001 |   10003 | 2003          | N
```

I wrote a query as shown below:

```
SELECT A.order_number, A.header_id, B.line_id, B.quantity, C.hold_price_id, C.released_flag
FROM Table_A a,
     Table_B b,
     Table_C c
WHERE a.header_id = b.header_id
AND   c.line_id = b.line_id
AND   a.order_number = '123';
```

My desire output is as shown below:

```
   order_number | header_id | line_id | quantity | hold_price_id | released_flag
            123 |     80001 |   10001 | 1        | 2001          | Y
            123 |     80001 |   10002 | 3        | 2002          | Y
            123 |     80001 |   10003 | 5        | 2003          | N
```

However the query show me the below result:

```
order_number | header_id | line_id | quantity      | hold_price_id | released_flag
         123 |     80001 |   10001 | 1             | 2001          | Y
         123 |     80001 |   10001 | 3             | 2002          | Y
         123 |     80001 |   10001 | 5             | 2003          | N
         123 |     80001 |   10002 | 1             | 2001          | Y
         123 |     80001 |   10002 | 3             | 2002          | Y
         123 |     80001 |   10002 | 5             | 2003          | N
         123 |     80001 |   10003 | 1             | 2001          | Y
         123 |     80001 |   10003 | 3             | 2002          | Y
         123 |     80001 |   10003 | 5             | 2003          | N
```

Is it something wrong on my query? Please advice.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: At minimum, need `AND c.header_id = b.header_id`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.  A simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.  *Always* use explicit `join`s:

```
SELECT A.order_number, A.header_id, B.line_id, B.quantity,
       C.hold_price_id, C.released_flag
FROM Table_A a JOIN
     Table_B b
     ON a.header_id = b.header_id JOIN
     Table_C c
     ON c.header_id = b.header_id AND c.line_id = b.line_id
WHERE a.order_number = '123';
```

Comment: Better approach than the accepted answer, when several tables are included in the query is easier to understand at first sight

Answer (score 8):

You haven't joined all of the common keys, so you are getting Cartesian results.  You needs to join a to c with header id, like so

```
SELECT A.order_number, A.header_id, B.line_id, B.quantity, C.hold_price_id, C.released_flag
FROM Table_A a,
     Table_B b,
     Table_C c
WHERE a.header_id = b.header_id
AND   c.line_id = b.line_id
AND   a.header_id = c.header_id
AND   a.order_number = '123';
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a.order_number, a.header_id, b.line_id, b.quantity ,c.hold_price_id,c.released_flag
FROM Table_A a cross JOIN 
     Table_B b cross join table_C c;

ORDER_NUMBER  HEADER_ID    LINE_ID   QUANTITY HOLD_PRICE_ID RELEASED_F

---

```
     123      80001      10001          1          2001 Y         
     123      80001      10002          3          2001 Y         
     123      80001      10003          5          2001 Y         
     123      80001      10001          1          2002 Y         
     123      80001      10002          3          2002 Y         
     123      80001      10003          5          2002 Y         
     123      80001      10001          1          2003 N         
     123      80001      10002          3          2003 N         
     123      80001      10003          5          2003 N
```

9 rows selected.