# joining three tables keeping void fields

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three table that I want to join by id. The first is the main containing always all informations on attributes. The others two could have null value for a certain id. In the result table I want to keep all fields of the three tables that for some row could be void.

main table

```
 id| attr1
----------
  1| hello
  2| hello2
```

second table

```
id| type
---------
 1| url
```

third table

```
 id| address
-------------
  2| www.example.com
```

the result i would obtain is

```
 id| attr1  | type | address
----------------------------------
  1| hello  | url  |
  2| hello2 |      | www.example.com
```

i have checked other similar post like this:[Joining 3 tables Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337086/joining-3-tables-oracle-sql)  but they doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `left join`s:

```
select m.*, s.type, t.address
from main m left join
     second s
     on m.id = s.id left join
     third t
     on m.id = t.id;
```

Comment: the last column "address" still not appears